# Hierarchical Nagios NRDS Configuration?

Tags: nagios

As far as I understand it, each client runs NRDS off of a single configuration file. That is, a list of commands it runs whose results the client then sends to the Nagios Server.

Is it possible to have the client run multiple config files? For instance, we would have an NRDS cfg for base Windows systems, but then an additional one for any specialized applications that might exist on that server.

Answer (score 1):

Every NRDS client has it's own config file on nagios server.

You can have different config files on different windows servers - each server has it's own config file.

But I'm not sure if one NRDS client can have multiple configs.